# How to use WebView on xcode 4.5.1

Tags: xcode, cocoa, webview, nsapplication

I'm new to programming and I need to embed a website in my application (which is blank; I only want to embed the website right now). I've been searching for it since 5:00 PM (It's now 9:30 PM) and I still didn't find anything about that.

What code do I need and in what file I need to write it? What do I have to link together?

I use Xcode 4.5.1 and I'm *trying* to do a Cocoa application for Mac OS X (not for iOS).

I'm sorry if some of my sentences are not clear, but English is not my primary language.

If you need more information in order to help me, just ask.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your AppDelegate.h file, add this line below the `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` line:

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
```

and add this line below the `@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;` line:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet WebView *webView;
```

Select your MainMenu.xib file.

Open the window inside it, then drag a WebView from the Object Library browser into the window. Align and size it.

There should be an icon representing your `AppController` object to the left of your UI layout. Control-drag from it to your `WebView` inside your window. (Do *not* control-drag from your `File's Owner` icon!) Release the mouse button. A contextual menu should appear, containing the word `webView`. Select it.

Add the framework `WebKit.framework` to your project. Right-click on your Frameworks folder in the resource list on the left side of the Xcode window. Choose "Add files to "<your project name>"... and select the framework using this path: `/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework`.

Select your AppDelegate.m file.

In your -applicationDidFinishLaunching: method, replace the comment with this code:

```
// I provided Apple's URL, but this is where you provide your own instead.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[[self webView] mainFrame] loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Build and run. When the window appears, you should see it load the web page you described in the URL.

A few final words:

I see that you're new here. What I've just done, in the context of Stack Overflow, is to give you a gift. You need to try a little harder looking for resources on the Web. I found two myself, but because they're a bit old (and the development tools look different enough), I embarked upon this answer. I want you to promise that you'll work harder to find answers for yourself. A great place to begin is by reading Apple's own [very excellent documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/SimpleBrowsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002025-CJBEHAAG).

Comment: Thanks a lot! And yes I promise to work harder to find. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Did you find the [Apple tutorial on this very subject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/SimpleBrowsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002025-CJBEHAAG):

```
WebView *webview = [[WebView alloc] init]; // or initialise using the modern-equivalent of InterfaceBuilder
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]]];
```

Comment: I tried. I put a Web View in my window and I put this code in AppDelegate.m. No errors, but I only get a white page...

Comment: This code needs to be in -awakeFromNib or -windowDidLoad -- not your delegate, which only gets called when a method there is triggered.