# How to send HTML to an embedded WebView without running a local webserver?

Tags: javascript, css, macos, cocoa, d3.js

I'd like to write a native Mac application. Instead of using the standard Mac GUI library (Cocoa?), though, I'd like to code the GUI using web technologies (HTML, CSS, Javascript). The main reason for developing with HTML/CSS/JS is that I'd like to use the d3.js data visualization library. The app's primary function is to visualize a large embedded database.

I've found [an answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13832380/765287) that explains how to embed a WebView in a Cocoa app. This is helpful, but not exactly what I'm looking for. My WebView doesn't need to access the internet, it just needs to render HTML/CSS/JS that's generated locally by my app.

Can anyone provide a code snippet that shows how to send HTML/CSS/JS from a desktop app to an embedded WebView? Is it possible to do this without running a local webserver?

I've got some experience writing web apps, but I'm new to mac programming.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that it might be less responsive that an Cocoa UI. Still, I'd like to at least try building a quick prototype to see how just how bad it'll be. Coding with web technologies that I'm already familiar with will save me TONS of time, and a bit of sluggishness in the UI might be a price I'm willing to pay.

Comment: Note -- I've edited the question to describe a specific problem, rather than to ask for a link to a tutorial. I think this is more in line with SO's guidelines. Could the question possibly be reopened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha. It turns out this is pretty simple. There's a solution here: [WebView load css on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2475467/765287)

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{

    NSString *resourcesPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString *htmlPath = [resourcesPath stringByAppendingString:@"/main.html"];
    [[self mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlPath]]];

}
```